# Copying the contents of a List<string> to text file while debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I need to compare the contents of a List for two runs for my program. What is the easiest way to copy the entire contents of the List manually from Visual Studio to notepad while stepping through the code. I can view the contents in QuickWatch. How can I copy all the elements?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can open the immediate window and run something like:

```
string.Join(", ", yourList)
```

or just

```
yourList
```

To open the immediate window: **Debug -> Windows -> Immediate** or the equivalent **Ctrl+D, I**

Answer (score 35):

Simply type this into the immediate window:

```
 File.WriteAllLines("foo.txt", yourList);
```

Or if it's a list of something other than strings:

```
 File.WriteAllLines("foo.txt", yourList.ConvertAll(Convert.ToString));
```

Comment: how to give the Location. Say i want to save it in 
C:\WriteLines\foo.txt

Comment: @harishannam You use `@"C:\WriteLines\foo.txt"` in place of `"foo.txt"`. Use the @ to avoid having to escape the backslashes.

Comment: I think you need to put yourList.ToArray() for this to work

Answer (score 8):

> I thinks this solution is better than.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
                list.Add("test1");
                list.Add("test2");
                list.Add("test3");
                list.Add("test4");

                File.WriteAllLines(Application.StartupPath + "\\Text.txt", list.ToArray());
                Process.Start("notepad.exe", Application.StartupPath + "\\Text.txt");
```

Answer (score 7):

### Easiest way:

1. Open **Watch** window
2. Type name of variable which is list
3. Select items which need ( for whole selection press 'shift' and click on first element and after that click on the last element of the list )
4. Press **Ctrl + C** or **click right** mouse button and select item from drop down 'Copy'
5. After that you can able to paste your text presentation of list to any text editor.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do a QuickWatch. In the quick watch window you can copy the values you want. If you want you can add some code to the top textbox in that window.

[image]